# Running Spring3 tutorial Build error

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I am doing a Spring3 tutorial. i downloaded the code from [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/11/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example.html). When i try to run it i get the following errors; I think i might be missing 1 or 2 Jar files. Can someone help me by pointing which Jar file i need to install and the link to do so.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" contact.jsp /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp  line 3  JSP Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags"   contact.jsp /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp  line 1  JSP Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  contact.jsp /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp  line 2  JSP Problem

### 2nd Error

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Autowired cannot be resolved to a type  ContactController.java  /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/java/net/viralpatel/contact/controller  line 19 Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   BindingResult cannot be resolved to a type  ContactController.java  /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/java/net/viralpatel/contact/controller  line 33 Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Entity cannot be resolved to a type Contact.java    /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/java/net/viralpatel/contact/form    line 9  Java Problem

There are 2 types of errors here, can some one help me resolve it.

Comment: Have you included jstl.jar and spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar?

Comment: Stop adding NEWBIE and BEGINNER to your titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tutorial uses maven. Unfortunaly it looks like they forget to specifiy the maven dependencies in the pom.xml.

So you can try to fix it, or try an other tutorial. (*I know I have mentioned this tutorial in one of my previous answers, but the question there was about the general structure of spring web controllers. -- sorry for the trouble*)

You can try this pom (*I have not tested it, but I feel a bit guilty*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <name>abc</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.156</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>abc</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Yeah this helps, but i have another 2 errors in the JSP files. Do you have any clue ?


Description Resource Path Location Type
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags" contact.jsp /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp line 1 JSP Problem
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" contact.jsp /Spring3HibernateMaven/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp line 2 JSP Problem

Comment: @Illep: no clue, the `http://www.springframework.org/tags/form` should be located in `spring/web-mvc-VERSION.jar` `/META-INF`

Answer (score 1):

@Illep: I was following the same tutorial and including

```
<properties>
 <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<!-- ... -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- ... -->
```

in pom.xml and puting a space between

```
prefix="spring" %>
```

did the trick.